# GDB cross-compilation for arm

Tags: python, c++, linux, gdb, arm

I want to debug  application on devices , i prefer to use gdb(ARM version) than gdb with gdbserver to debug, because there is a dashboard , a visual interface for GDB in Python.

It must cooperation with gdb(ARM version) on devices,so i need to cross compiling a ARM version of gdb with python, the command used shows below:

> ./configure --build=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --host=arm
>   -target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc --with-python=python3.3 --libdir=/u01/rootfs/lib/ --prefix=/u01/cross-compilation/gdb-7.7.1/arm_install --disable-libtool --disable-tui --with-termcap=no --with-curses=no

But finally a error message appeared during make:

> checking for python3.3... missing configure: error: unable to find
>   python program python3.3

Here I had a python3.3 binaries and libraries whicha are cross-compiled for ARM.
Please give me any suggestion.
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing library headers (something like python3-dev).
To install it on Ubuntu or similar start by sudo apt-get install python3-dev.

Or if you don't plan to use python scripting in gdb, you can configure with "--without-python".

As far as I can tell you are also not configuring gdb correctly. You can leave out --build (if you are building on PC arm-none-linux... is wrong). Your host should be arm-none-linux-gnueabi, not just arm.